# What to consider when choosing motherboard when I need to choose my boot disk from several hard drives?

Tags: motherboard, hard-disk

I would like to put two ssd drivess in my new PC. One with Windows 10 and the other with the latest Ubuntu.

I tried this with my current setup without success, but I fear my RAID controller is interfering.

Also, I tried to plug some portable device and boot from USB. This works when you've installed the Ubuntu ISO image on the hard drive, but I would like to be able to boot the installed system. Installing seemed to work, just booting failed by dropping me into a grub console.

However, this is a hardware platform, so I'm asking for a motherboard or some controller stuff? Any recommendations that support dual booting?

I currently have a [Dell Studio XPS 8100](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_studio_xps_desktop/studio-xps-8100_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf)

Comment: My apologies for the delay, I tend to use the site during the daytime hours (at least daytime relative to myself). As far as what I want to know, what RAID controller are you using? I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to dual boot based on your setup, unless the RAID controller is a wonky one, but even then that shouldn't be too big of an issue. After you've booted into Ubuntu did you set the boot order? [Near the bottom here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html) under the heading "Changing the boot order" may be helpful.

Comment: If not, then a hardware change/omission may be necessary! PS: sorry for the double post.

Comment: This is probably just a grub configuration error, and or MBR issue.

Comment: @Steviet I think my BIOS has no UEFI mode, but probably the new one will have. I did not want to overwrite the Windows Bootloader with Grub. And I thought when I am using a separate USB drive, with just one OS on it, I could achieve this. When pressing F8 on startup I can choose from which device to boot from. This is the point where booting from USB drive failed and grub console appeared.

Comment: @Armin for your idea of switch with the F8 key, you need to install each OS with only 1 drive connected.  This is the simplest way.  You can modify grub to point to windows and vice versus, but this is far from simple.